# How to return MagicMock object from a method of a class that was mocked using patch in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, mocking, python-unittest

I just started with mocks in python and I got to this use case and can't figure a working solution.

I want to return a MagicMock object from a class which was mocked using patch.

This is the folder structure:

```bash
.
├── tests
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── test.py
└── utils
    ├── Creator.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── SecondLayer.py
    └── User.py

2 directories, 6 files
```

**SecondLayer.py**

```py
class SecondLayer:
    def do_something_second_layer(self):
        print("do_something_second_layer")
        return 1
```

**Creator.py**

```py
from utils.SecondLayer import SecondLayer

class Creator:
    def get_second_layer(self):
        second_layer = SecondLayer()
        return second_layer
```

**User.py**

```py
from utils.Creator import Creator

class User:

    def __init__(self):
        self.creator = Creator()

    def user_do_something(self):
        second_layer = self.creator.get_second_layer()
        if second_layer.do_something_second_layer() == 1:
            print("Returned 1")
        else:
            print("Returned 2")
```

And the test file:

```py
import unittest
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, Mock, patch
from utils.User import User

# python3 -m unittest discover -p "*test*"

class TestUser(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.mock_second_layer = MagicMock(name="mock_second_layer")
        config_creator = {
            'get_second_layer.return_value': self.mock_second_layer}

        self.creator_patcher = patch(
            'utils.User.Creator', **config_creator)

        self.mock_creator = self.creator_patcher.start()

        self.user = User()
        print(f'{self.mock_creator.mock_calls}')

    def test_run_successful_run(self):
        self.user.user_do_something()

        # Does not prin calls to do_something_second_layer
        print(f'self.mock_second_layer.mock_calls')
        print(f'{self.mock_second_layer}')
        print(f'{self.mock_second_layer.mock_calls}')
        # Prints all calls also for the nested ones eg: get_second_layer().do_something_second_layer()
        print(f'self.mock_creator.mock_calls')
        print(f'{self.mock_creator}')
        print(f'{self.mock_creator.mock_calls}')

    def tearDown(self):
        self.mock_creator.stop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

When I run the tests, I receive this output:

```py
$ python3 -m unittest discover -p "*test*"
[call()]
Returned 2

self.mock_second_layer.mock_calls
<MagicMock name='mock_second_layer' id='140404085721648'>
[call.__str__()]

self.mock_creator.mock_calls
<MagicMock name='Creator' id='140404085729616'>
[call(),
 call().get_second_layer(),
 call().get_second_layer().do_something_second_layer(),
 call().get_second_layer().do_something_second_layer().__eq__(1),
 call.__str__()]
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.002s
```

As you can see: `self.mock_second_layer.mock_calls` doesn't print the mock calls to `do_something_second_layer`, it looks like it's not injected by the `patch` call.

Can someone give me a solution on how can inject that `self.mock_second_layer` via `patch` and be able to then access the calls that were made on it? I tried for a few hours and I just can't get it working..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation

The problem comes from the fact that you provide the wrong (and quite exotic) keyword arguments to `patch` via that `config_creator` dictionary in `setUp`.

What you are doing here is completely patching the `Creator` class, replacing the **class** (this is important) with a `MagicMock` instance, and then assigning the `get_second_layer` attribute on that mock object yet another mock, which is instructed to return `self.mock_second_layer`, when called.

This happens because of the way [`patch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch) works. The first argument is the **target** to be patched. In this case you tell it to patch the `Creator` class.

Arbitrary keyword arguments are just passed along to the newly created mock to turn into its attributes. You provide `**{'get_second_layer.return_value': self.mock_second_layer}`. By the way, this would not even be possible, if you tried to use regular keyword-argument notation because of the dot in the key.

Then, after the patch is applied, your `Creator` class is that mock, you instantiate `User`, which in turn calls `Creator` in its constructor. Typically, this would instantiate a `Creator` object, but since that is no longer a class at this point, it just calls your mock. Since you did not define a **return value for that mock** (just for its `get_second_layer` attribute), it does what it does by default, namely returning yet another new `MagicMock` object, and this is what is assigned to `self.creator` inside `User.__init__`.

There is nothing specified for that last mock. It is created on the fly. Any attribute access after that just results in the usual `MagicMock` behavior, which is basically *"sure I have this attribute, here ya go"* and creates a another mock for that.

Thus, when you call `user_do_something` in your test method, you just get a chain of generic mock calls that are all created on the fly.

You can actually see this happening, when you look at that last list of calls you provided:

```
call(),
call().get_second_layer(),
call().get_second_layer().do_something_second_layer(),
call().get_second_layer().do_something_second_layer().__eq__(1),
call.__str__()
```

The first one is the "instantiation" of `Creator` (no arguments).
The rest are also all "on-the-fly"-created mock objects.

If you are now wondering, where your `mock_second_layer` mock went, you can try a simple thing: Just add `print(Creator.get_second_layer())` anywhere in `User.__init__` for example. Notice that to get it, you need to omit the parentheses after `Creator`.

---

### Solution 1

If you really want to mock the entire `Creator` class, you need to be careful to define what the mock replacing it will return because you are not using the class itself in your code, but **instances** of it. So you could set up a *specific* mock object that it returns, and then define its attributes accordingly.

Here is an example: (I put all your classes into one `code` module)

```py
from unittest import TestCase, main
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, patch

from . import code

class TestUser(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.mock_second_layer = MagicMock(name="mock_second_layer")
        self.mock_creator = MagicMock(
            name="mock_creator",
            get_second_layer=MagicMock(return_value=self.mock_second_layer)
        )
        self.creator_patcher = patch.object(
            code,
            "Creator",
            return_value=self.mock_creator,
        )
        self.creator_patcher.start()
        self.user = code.User()
        super().setUp()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.creator_patcher.stop()
        super().tearDown()

    def test_run_successful_run(self):
        self.user.user_do_something()
        print('\nself.mock_second_layer.mock_calls')
        print(f'{self.mock_second_layer}')
        print(f'{self.mock_second_layer.mock_calls}')
        print('\nself.mock_creator.mock_calls')
        print(f'{self.mock_creator}')
        print(f'{self.mock_creator.mock_calls}')
```

Output:

```
Returned 2

self.mock_second_layer.mock_calls
<MagicMock name='mock_second_layer' id='...'>
[call.do_something_second_layer(),
 call.do_something_second_layer().__eq__(1),
 call.__str__()]

self.mock_creator.mock_calls
<MagicMock name='mock_creator' id='...'>
[call.get_second_layer(), call.__str__()]
```

Notice that when I `start` the `creator_patcher`, I don't capture its output. We don't need it here because it is just the mock replacing the **class**. We are interested in the instance returned by it, which we created beforehand and assigned to `self.mock_creator`.

Also, I am using [`patch.object`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch-object), just because I find its interface easier to work with and more intuitive. You can still transfer this approach to regular `patch` and it will work the same way; you'll just need to again provide the full path as a string instead of the `target` and `attribute` separately.

---

### Solution 2

If you don't actually need to patch the entire class (because initialization is super simple and has no side effects), you could get away with just specifically patching the `Creator.get_second_layer` method:

```py
from unittest import TestCase, main
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, patch

from . import code


class TestUser(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.mock_second_layer = MagicMock(name="mock_second_layer")
        self.get_second_layer_patcher = patch.object(
            code.Creator,
            "get_second_layer",
            return_value=self.mock_second_layer,
        )
        self.mock_get_second_layer = self.get_second_layer_patcher.start()
        self.user = code.User()
        super().setUp()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.get_second_layer_patcher.stop()
        super().tearDown()

    def test_run_successful_run(self):
        self.user.user_do_something()
        print('\nself.mock_second_layer.mock_calls')
        print(f'{self.mock_second_layer}')
        print(f'{self.mock_second_layer.mock_calls}')
        print('\nself.mock_get_second_layer.mock_calls')
        print(f'{self.mock_get_second_layer}')
        print(f'{self.mock_get_second_layer.mock_calls}')
```

Output:

```
Returned 2

self.mock_second_layer.mock_calls
<MagicMock name='mock_second_layer' id='...'>
[call.do_something_second_layer(),
 call.do_something_second_layer().__eq__(1),
 call.__str__()]

self.mock_get_second_layer.mock_calls
<MagicMock name='get_second_layer' id='...'>
[call(), call.__str__()]
```

This accomplishes essentially the same thing with a bit less code. But I would argue this is less "pure" in the sense that it technically does not fully decouple the `User.user_do_something` test from `Creator`. So I would probably still go with the first option.

Comment: Thank you so much for the complete explanation!